# How to add System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll in Windows Phone 8 project?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, rss

I am trying to build an rss feed app. and i want to add `System.Servicemodel.Syndication`. But when i am trying to add, it is saying a reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project. After reading some post on how to solve it, i try to unblock the assembly but i found no unblock button. That means the project is already unblocked.
So how can i solve the issue?? Is there any alternative way to read rss?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the documentation here [Adding a Reference to the Syndication DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487167%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_AddingaReferencetotheSyndicationDLL) you need to install the Silverlight 4 SDK and then reference the v4 version of the dll located at Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v4.0/Libraries/Client/.

[Windows Phone is based on Siverlight v4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237342%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

this assembly is designed for silverlight 5 so you cannot add to the project due to compatibility issues regarding .Net 3.5 +

Answer (score 0):

See the article at
http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/silverlight-for-windows-phone-programming-tip-2
on how to use LINQ to XML instead

(btw that article says the alternative is to use the respective dll from the Silverlight 3 SDK)

another way is to use a Web Service and parse the RSS on the server instead, see example at:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83859/A-Simple-Silverlight-RSS-Reader